# Deny access to web page from browser and allow from C# application

Tags: c#, php, apache, .htaccess

My `.htaccess` code :

```
<Directory /var/www/electronic_signature/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    <Files /var/www/electronic_signature/mkcnf.php>
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

From browser everything is ok, but I call a `mkcnf.php` page through C# application; where the `mkcnf.php` page calls another php page, this exception appears:

> The remote server returned an error 403 Forbidden

Why is this error appearing, even though I have allowed this page locally?

Comment: how you call that file? using HTTP protocol?

Comment: WebClient.downloadData()

Comment: Is the C# application running on the same box?

Comment: no , it's the client application, whereas the php is the server app

Comment: "From browser everything is ok" - is this from the browser running on the webserver?

Comment: what is the URI? (remote URI for the file)

Comment: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/electronic_signature/mkcnf.php'

Comment: from browser , i mean when i call the page from browser, so i want to call it from C# application only , and deny calling from browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowing access to the box that is serving the page.  You are denying access to everything else, including the C# application that isn't running on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: no , i only want to deny from browsing it, and allow the C# application to call this page

Comment: not according to your .htaccess - deny from all - denies all except the allow from 127.0.0.1 override

Comment: but mkcnf.php located in 127.0.0.1? so if it calls another page it can

Comment: paste the code it is using to call the other page.  Is it an include or require?

Comment: is the c# application calling the mkcnf.php page?

Comment: The 403 error is coming from the call from the c# app to mkcnf.php.  The script never makes it to the include.

Comment: i think so also, now what's the problem? i allowed the page that called from C#

Comment: what you mean by 'new .htaccess'?

Comment: how did you allow the page that called from C#?  Did you update the htaccess?

Comment: same i wrote :  <Files /var/www/electronic_signature/mkcnf.php>
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Files>

Comment: 127.0.0.1 represents the local machine.  the webserver doesn't see the C# app machine as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: what is the C# app's ip address?

Comment: it depends on internet connection, no ip specified

Comment: move all the files that should be accessed publicly to a different folder and set `Allow from all` on the folder